# How to load a URL in Java using a proxy using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, http, url, httpclient, ping

Hi I am trying to test the response time by using URL of a server in JAVA using Apache HttpClient

here is my code

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpMethod method = new HeadMethod("http://www.google.com/");
    StopWatch sWatch = new StopWatch();

    try {

        sWatch.start();
    client.executeMethod(method);

    System.out.println(sWatch.toString());

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

MY PROBLEM is I can access the `www.google.com` from my browser but When I try to execute that logic is giving  This exception

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:280)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at com.sampl.DAP.CheckResponse.checkStatus(CheckResponse.java:31)
at com.sampl.DAP.CheckResponse.main(CheckResponse.java:44)
```

Comment: Is there any proxy servers through which the traffic is routed?. If so, try adding the proxy settings in your code.

Comment: This is a really old version of http components. Consider upgrading.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes I have proxy server that routes the traffic .. if so then how to add proxy Settings in my code any examples plz

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Upgrading ? How ?

Comment: [Just get the new version.](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Comment: @looser try `System.getProperties().put("proxyHost","<proxyIP>"); System.getProperties().put("proxyPort","<proxyPort>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author djc39_000
 */
public class URLBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {            
            URLConnection uc =  new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection(
                    new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.example.com", 3128))
            );
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
            String line;            
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(URLBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(URLBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I formated the program this way so that if you don't have a proxy you can comment out that line and everything else will still work. If you do it with making a var Proxy proxy = new Proxy(...) then you have to comment multi lines.

Comment: Will you elaborate `InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.example.com", 3128)` plz ?

Comment: "This class implements an IP Socket Address (IP address + port number) It can also be a pair (hostname + port number), in which case an attempt will be made to resolve the hostname. If resolution fails then the address is said to be unresolved but can still be used on some circumstances like connecting through a proxy."

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a library. I would recommend using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org). The below code has been tested.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
Response response= Jsoup.connect(location)
       .ignoreContentType(true)
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")  
       .referrer("http://www.google.com")   
       .timeout(12000) 
       .followRedirects(true)
       .execute();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
```